# campo personalizados joomla

Tags: joomla3

Necesito ayuda para crear un campo personalizado tipo upload archivo de audio y pdf.
Pero me esta siendo imposible encontrar información relacionada y los campos multimedia despliegan la ventana mítica ventana de upload/select image de Joomla dejando al descubierto el resto de archivos y para este proyecto me gustaría un upload de documentos que fuera algo mas simple y directo con una prevista antes de guardar.

He revisado algún documento que habla de duplicar uno de los campos y costumizarlo pero resulta algo difícil  y me preguntaba si alguien lo ha probado ya y si me podría ayudar a implementarlo. Hasta ahora estuve utilizando componentes CCK pero para este proyecto me interesaba explotar el core de joomla.

Espero que me puedan ayudar.

Answer (score 0):

Lo siento tendría que haberme documentado antes y he visto que existen un monton de campos [JED - Custom Fields](https://extensions.joomla.org/tags/custom-fields/)

Existe la posibilidad de crear tus propios campos a modo plugin que parece bastante satisfactorio y practico.

Un saludo y espero que a alguien le preste la info.